# angular -Which form type to choose Model-Driven or Template Driven form?

Tags: angular, model-driven-development

when i use Model-Driven form like :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <p>
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text"  [ngModel]="user.firstName" required>
  </p>
  `,
  providers: [myService]
})
```

and when i use Template Driven form like :

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
      <p>
         <label>First Name:</label>
         <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
      </p>
      `,
      providers: [myService]
    })
```

I think above both things do same functionality.
so, I get little confusion which one is preferable while start new project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I think above both things do same functionality. so, I get little confusion which one is preferable while start new project ?*

You have not fully explored the forms as of now i guess . There are certain things which is hard or even not possible at present with template driven forms in Angular .

Things like Form array adding and removing controls dynamically . Listing to Each control and doing stuff this is more practical and easy in Reactive Forms . And i feel going forward Angular team will switch completely to Reactive forms and that is way to go .

Some Reasons i say so is - this [**PR**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9615) to support NgModelArray in Template Driven Forms

More on [**Reactive Forms**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive) and [T**emplate Driven Forms**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/template).

Now its your call what you prefer.